# Filter out bad date values

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table in SQL Server that was given to me to take the data and convert expirationDate (`varchar(4000)`) to `DATE`.

This table was populated by an Excel sheet that's why it has different dates.

I need to somehow convert all of them into one format and cast as `DATE` with a `SELECT` statement.

Sample data in `expirationDate`:

```
2099-09-09
NULL
NA
8/25/12
12/21/11
na
2010-11-07
2013-10-07
NULL
3/25/12
tbd
NA
N/A
2009-04-17
2011-02-21
02/15/2011
08/31/11
NULL
2012-11-06
na
2011-12-21
2011-10-09
NA
2009-04-17
NA
2/29/12
```

I tried:

```
select CASE WHEN ISDATE(expirationDate) = 1 THEN CAST(expirationDate AS DATE) 
       ELSE cast(null as DATE) END
 FROM [dbo].[ComponentData]
```

But it is throwing error:

```
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

I also tried:

```
CONVERT(varchar(4000),CAST(expirationDate AS DATE),100)
```

But same thing... :(

Can anyone help me fix this?

Comment: You might try doing it in two steps with the isDate in the where clause. You might be having trouble with the fact that CASE isn't always going to use short circuit evaluation.

Comment: select  CONVERT(varchar(4000),CAST(expirationDate AS DATE),100)
 from [dbo].[ComponentData]
 where ISDATE(expirationDate) = 1 still throwing error

Comment: What version of SQL are you using? I might have an idea.

Comment: sql server 2008 LOL @Lamak

Comment: @Angelina that isn't a version of SQL Server, it's for Oracle

Comment: How **can** you fix this if there are different formats of dates?. Which date do you want for this: "01/02/2013"?, is it January 2nd or February 1st?

Comment: @Angelina It doesn't seem like that here: `8/25/12` or `02/15/2011`

Comment: @Lamak ...I know. If I do below select statement on these varchars, that's what gives me back...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i got it:

Testing:

```
select CAST(REPLACE(CONVERT(NVARCHAR, componentExpirationDate,103), '/', '-') as date)
 from [dbo].[BatchComponent]
 where ISDATE(componentExpirationDate) = 1
```

Output:

```
2099-09-09
2012-01-11
2010-09-27
2012-08-25
2011-12-21
2010-09-01
2016-02-02
2009-05-08
2010-11-07
2013-10-07
```

Change to CASE WHEN:

```
select CASE WHEN ISDATE(expirationDate) = 1 THEN CAST(REPLACE(CONVERT(NVARCHAR, expirationDate,103), '/', '-') as date) 
        ELSE cast(null as date) END
     FROM [dbo].[ComponentData]
```

Thank you all for your help.

Comment: https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length.aspx